# How to ng-include at click on link

Tags: angularjs, templates, search, controller, include

I'm new on AngularJS and I need to include another template by clicking on a link.

I have a nav.html and a header.html. Both included in the index.html.
In header.html I have

```
<li class="search-box visible-md visible-lg" data-ng-include=" 'views/calls/search.html' ">
```

calls/search.html

```
<div class="input-group" data-ng-controller="callSearchCtrl">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search text-muted"></i></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suchen..."></div>
```

And I have to include another template in the header by clicking on a menu point (i.e. Contacts) to load the contacts/search.html

```
<div class="input-group" data-ng-controller="contactsSearchCtrl">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search text-muted"></i></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suchen..."></div>
```

to get another search controller.

The case is, that I have a search bar in the header, where I want to search in the loaded content template.

Maybe I've got the wrong mindset to solve this...

Anyone knows a solution?

ADDITION:

Now I put different ng-clicks in my nav like:

```
            <a href="#/contacts/contacts" data-ng-click="selectType('contacts')"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span>Kontakte</span></a>
```

But do I have to put the scope function in my HeaderCtrl or in my NavCtrl?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english :-)

Cheers
bambamboole

Comment: See documentation about ng-switch may be that should help. Or you can also call a scope function which will update another scope variable which contains actual path to ng-include. Hope that helps

Comment: @bambamboole re: Addition - It'll need to be in a scope that both templates share. More generally, I think you may be using more controllers than you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and probably most idiomatic is as @coder-john suggests.

```
data-ng-include="search.option"
```

In your controller,

```
$scope.search = {};
$scope.selectType = function (type) {
    $scope.search.option = 'views/'+type+'/search.html';
};
$scope.selectType('calls');
```

where your menu options should invoke the proper handlers, such as

```
data-ng-click="selectType('calls')"
```

or

```
data-ng-click="selectType('contacts')"
```

as appropriate.

Comment: hmm, but my navbar and my header(with searchbar) got different controllers.